# Java Swing Library, concerning Stopwatch

Tags: java, swing

I have created a small GUI designed to use apache lang's stopwatch. When a specific textbox is focused (using .isFocusOwner() ) a stopwatch timer is started and when the user fills in the textbox with the correct string and clicks a confirm button an actionPerformed is used to stop the timer and print the time.

This happens three times within my application. The code below is how I planned to accomplish this, but the timer seems to malfunction upon reaching the last textbox confirmation.

The label_____Good is only visible if the button is pressed and the correct string is within the textbox.

Should I be trying to utilize actionPerformed within each individual textbox?

```
while(!completed){


            if(text1.isFocusOwner() && !labelEmailGood.isVisible()){                
                if(!stopWatch.isStarted()){ 
                    stopWatch.start();
                }else{

                }
            }


            if(text2.isFocusOwner() && !labelBankGood.isVisible()){
                if(!stopWatch.isStarted()){
                    stopWatch.start();
                }else{

                }
                return;
            }

            if(text3.isFocusOwner() && !labelFaceGood.isVisible()){             
                if(!stopWatch.isStarted()){
                    stopWatch.start();
                }else{

                }
                return;
            }

            if(labelEmailGood.isVisible() && labelBankGood.isVisible() && labelFaceGood.isVisible()){
                completed = true;
            }else{

            }

        }


private JButton makeButtonPass2(){

        buttPass2.setText("Confirm Password");
        buttPass2.setBounds(250, 190, 160, 30);
        buttPass2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e1){

                String pass2 = getPass2();
            //The password Confirmation
                //If nothing is in the text box
                if(text2.getText().equals("")){
                    labelBankGood.setVisible(false);
                    labelBankBad.setVisible(false);
                }
                //If the correct password is in the text box
                else if(text2.getText().equals(pass2)){
                    labelBankGood.setVisible(true);
                    labelBankBad.setVisible(false);
                    stopWatch.stop();
                    info2.addLoginTime(Float.valueOf(stopWatch.toString().substring(6, 11)));
                    System.out.println(stopWatch.toString().substring(4, 11));
                    stopWatch.reset();
                }
                //If the incorrect password is in the text box
                else if(!text2.getText().equals(pass2)){
                    labelBankBad.setVisible(true);
                    info2.addUnSuccessfulLogTimes();
                    labelBankGood.setVisible(false);
                }

            }
        });
        return buttPass2;
    }
```

[image: What the GUI looks like.]

An excellent idea was to add a `FocusListener`, the solution looking similar to what is posted below:

```
text1.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
                stopWatch.reset();
                stopWatch.start();
                return;
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
                stopWatch.stop();
                return;
            }
        });
```

Comment: I think you should have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) - I think a better choice might be to use a `FocusListener` to start/stop a timer, when a timer is stopped (or a timeout occurs), you should check the state

Comment: Are you referring to each textbox having a FocusListener to start the timer?

Comment: Basically, yes.  You can use the `FocusListener` to monitor the `focusGained` (and optionally the `focusLost`) event of each field to control the timer.  You'd then have a "common" `stop` method which would stop the timer and validate the state